# Why am I not notified if a question I follow gets edited?

Tags: support, status-completed, follow-posts

I have been annoyed on a few occasions today because I started following a question and whenever an edit was made I was never notified of it. I could understand if the edit was made by the OP or in short succession, but the edits were made by a 3rd-party and long after the question was asked or a previous edit made.

Also, when I use the Ajax button to refresh the question, the button changes back to "follow" as if I never followed the question at all.

Does the follow feature no longer apply to edits? Is it only comments and new answers now?

Comment: I could also understand not being notified of trivial edits (eg those less than 6 characters, as OP would not be notified either) but I assume that you’re talking about substantial edits.

Comment: Yes, strange thing I got one notification today. I am not sure if there is a bug or glitch or an I misunderstanding how it works.

Comment: This appears to be resolved now. More info https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zU-o6cr9DeLKB3na9aEld13Ixf30f4qpGWPidILtmPs/view